# What is wrong with this hashmap, I keep getting incompatible types

Tags: java, hashmap

```
//vehicle
double type[] = {0, 1.0, 1.3, 1.6, 2, 2.4, 2.7};
String carType[] = {"","Compact Car", "Small Car", "Mid Size Car", "Full Size Car", "Truck", "16 Wheeler"};
HashMap <Integer, Double> vehicle = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
for(int y = 1; y<6; y++)
{
    vehicle.put(y, type[y]);
}
HashMap <Integer, String> CarName = new HashMap<>();
for(int a = 1; a<6; a++)
{
    CarName.put(a, carType[a]);
}

/**
 * Now begin to read the file and reference the tables. 
 */
int gate1, vehicle1, toll1, factor, cost;
String car;
System.out.println(EasyFormat.format("Car Type", 0)+EasyFormat.format("Base Toll", 15)+EasyFormat.format("Factor", 22)+EasyFormat.format("Cost",30));
while(file.hasNext())
{
    gate1 = file.nextInt();
    vehicle1 = file.nextInt();
    factor = (Double)  vehicle.get(vehicle1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
int factor; //other variables as well
//more code...
while(file.hasNext()) {
    //more code...
    factor = (Double)  vehicle.get(vehicle1);
}
```

`factor` is `int` type and you're trying to assing a `Double` to it.

Declare `factor` as `double` or use `Double#intValue`. I would prefer to declare `factor` as `double` and let unboxing do its job.

Comment: The moral of the story being that you shouldn't declare a variable out of the scope where you are using it. An `int factor = (Double)vehicle.get...` might have raised an eyebrow of the writer.

Comment: @laune that's a good point, but won't solve the main problem :)

Comment: It might even have avoided it ;-))